# Tracking Expression Engine Blog articles & blog categories in GA

Tags: google-analytics

we have built a blog in expression engine and have added a snippet of code which is

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"NewsArticle","mainEntityOfPage":{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"https://digitalmarketinginstitute.com/blog/what-does-an-seo-manager-do"},"headline":"What Does an SEO Manager Do?","image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://dmi-uploads.imgix.net/general/SEO_Blog.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1200&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=60&w=1600&s=2afb9350b0e80e782baa4c94d3c447bb","width":800,"height":600},"author":{"@type":"Person","name":"carla@digitalmarketinginstitute.com"},"datePublished":"2019-01-11T11:01:00+00:00","dateModified":"2019-01-11T15:35:49+00:00","publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Digital Marketing Institute","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://assets.digitalmarketinginstitute.com/assets/images/design/logo_redesign.png","width":32,"height":32}},"description":"Digital marketing is a requirement of any business or organization that wants to get noticed by today’s consumer. It offers a world of possibilities when it comes to career choices spanning a wide variety of skill sets. One of the most sought-after skills in digital marketing is the SEO expert."}</script> <span
```

data-ga-news-category="{categories limit='1'}{category_url_title}" style="display: none;">

How can I add this to GA as currently its not showing in the events area in GA.

Comment: what exactly you're going to add to GA? JSON LD snippets have nothing to do with analytics events tracking

Comment: Is there anyway to track in GA various blog categories. for this post here https://digitalmarketinginstitute.com/blog/what-does-a-digital-marketer-do its under the category Careers. Is there anyway to be able to get GTM triggers to search Text on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Google Analytics [Content Groupings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en) to track your content taxonomy. Most probably you'll need to modify your tracking code implicitly to pass these data to Analytics. Within GTM you may use 'Enable overriding settings' feature with Analytics tags to pass Content Grouping values.